# How do I configure Serilog for multiple Environments appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration, serilog, seq, seq-logging

I am trying to configure appsettings.json so that I have multiple Serilog variables for each of our environments(Dev, UAT, Prod etc) I have the following serilog that works for dev:

```
    "Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
  "Using": [
    "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
    "Serilog.Sinks.Seq"
  ],
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "Console"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Seq",
      "Args": {
        "serverUrl": "https://seq-dev.test.com"
      },
      "Properties": {
        "Application": "Console.Sample",
        "Environment": "Local"
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

My current solution is to have an array of Serilog instance. I am going to be passing an arg into main specificying which environment I want and I should use that Seq instance(Example: args: Environment="d" for dev - this should pull the dev Serilog)

```
    "d": {
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Seq"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "https://seq-dev.test.com"
        },
        "Properties": {
          "Application": "Console.Sample",
          "Environment": "Local"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
"q": {
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Seq"
    ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "https://seq-dev.test.com"
        },
        "Properties": {
          "Application": "Console.Sample",
          "Environment": "Local"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) thing.

You need to specify a appsettings json for each environment

[image]

The one that will be used by the application is determine by this ENV variable

[image]

Comment: Thank you Paul for the quick answer! This is more of a utility app and will basically ping each environment at any time based off the command line args provided. Its not like this will be hosted in a dev environment and it will only hit dev. Therefor I am not sure Environment Variables are the right solution. Is there a way to set environment variables based off command line args? Or specify which app settings.json to use via command line "dev", "prod" ect? Thanks in advanced

Comment: Is this a asp.net core app? or a console .net core app? In any case both would have a section of code that handles the reading of the appsettings.json. I would think you just set your variable logic there